# Query sqlite table from python 3 includs brackets when querying one attribute, and not when querying many

Tags: python, sqlite, output

I'm new to Python, using Python 3 I am trying to query a sqlite database. However if I query only one attribute the result incluces brackets - which I don't want. When doing similar query on two attributes, the brackets don't show.

Example, querying 2 attributes:

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT Employee_fname, Employee_lname FROM employee"):
        Employee_fname, Employee_lname = row
        print(Employee_fname, Employee_lname)
```

results in:

```
Amanda Anderson
Benny Baldrick
Charles Charlsson
David Davidson
```

Example, querying 1 attribute (removing Employee_lname from the query) :

```
for row in c.execute("SELECT Employee_fname FROM employee"):
        Employee_fname = row
        print(Employee_fname)
```

results in:

```
('Amanda',)
('Benny',)
('Charles',)
('David',)
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `for row in c.execute(...):` assigns `row` to a tuple.  In your first snippet, you unpacked that tuple to two fields.  In your second snippet, you assigned the tuple to a variable.  if you want the seond snippet to behave like the first, try `Employee_fname = row[0]`.

Comment: also it's not a bug, it's a feature... ;)

Comment: Of course.. Thank you Alan, it was the solution I needed.